# How to hide get variable name from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i've used htaccess for something like this

```
domain.com/bacaberita.php -> domain.com/baca-berita
```

and i need passing get varible like this

```
domain.com/bacaberita.php?id=xy0001
```

how to hide the variable id so the url going to be `domain.com/baca-berita/xyz0001`

i'm using htacces code

```
RewriteRule ^baca-berita bacaberita.php
RewriteRule ^baca-berita/(.*) bacaberita.php?id=$1
```

but it throws id was empty

i've try this code only

```
RewriteRule ^baca-berita/(.*) bacaberita.php?id=$1
```

it work but the css and all images file can not called in the page

Comment: Your first rule matches `baca-berita/xyz0001` already, so it gets rewritten to `bacaberita.php`. You need to anchor your pattern not only at the beginning, but at the end as well, if you want to avoid that. `^baca-berita$`, or `^baca-berita/?$` if you want to allow an optional trailing slash. And in general, you should keep your RewriteRules ordered from more specific to less specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put some rewrite conditions before your rewrite rules to ignore those asset files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets
RewriteRule ^baca-berita/(.*) bacaberita.php?id=$1
```

This tells the server to check that the files or directories exist, then to ignore them in the rewrite if in those directories.

---

**Update**

You also want to make sure your assets inside `bacaberita.php` are linked from the root of the site and not relatively. You can do this by ensuring you always use a `/` at the beginning:

```
<!-- incorrect: looks for styles in domain.com/bacaberita/assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css">

<!-- correct: looks for styles in domain.com/assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
```

Comment: my assets folder structure is like this assets -> css, images i tried this still won't work RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets

Comment: Sorry, I missed two important conditions (checking the files/dirs exist). I updated the answer.

Comment: all of my styling file like bootstrap images css js was inside the assets folder i've tried your tips the page still unstyled and the problem only occur this baca-berita page

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem and I updated my answer above